# App Store Connect: How to get to the "ready to submit" status?

Tags: app-store-connect

I would like to publish an app on the app store. To Test some features the app has to have the "ready to submit" status. Right now it has the "prepare for submission" status even tough I uploaded everything mandatory. How do I get to the next status?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The status will automatically update when you have all the required information registered.

For the software build itself, there's a delay from when you upload it until it has been processed by Apple. You can see the state of the upload in App Store Connect, and you'll also receive an email when it has been processed. This usually takes only a relatively short amount of time (i.e. usually much less than 30 minutes).

In addition there's a lot of information you must register about your app. These are all detailed on App Store Connect, so I would suggest simply clicking through the various sub-tabs on the "App Store" tab for the app to ensure everything is filled out. This includes such things as:

- App name, description, keywords and similar meta data
- App icon
- Screenshots (note that you need them in various sizes)
- Various URLs for support requests, marketing, etc.
- Pricing
- A privacy policy and filling out the privacy questionnaire
- Rating (to determine if there's an age requirement)

Comment: Is there a way to highlight what's missing? I think I filled out every information needed, but it won't switch to "ready to submit"

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I was missing is that you not only have to fill in the information about privacy, but you have to also publish it.

A way to find out what is missing is to click the "add to review" button. You later have to confirm it, so no worries. It isn't send to apple immediately.